# Overloading Operator % in PowerShell Classes

Tags: powershell

When creating custom classes in PowerShell 5 or later, one can overload the comparison operators (by deriving your class from `[System.IComparable]` and creating a method `CompareTo()`) and the four "arithmetic" operators `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` (by creating static methods `op_Addition`, `op_Subtraction`, `op_Multiply`, and `op_Division`).

What is the static method needed to overload the modulo operator `%`? Or is this simply not possible?

Comment: pls add complete Sourcecode for testing

Comment: @f6a4 - There's no extant source code; I've already mastered the overloading of the comparison operators and four-function mathematics operators. The problem is that I haven't found any reference for overloading the modulo operator `%`; that's what I'm asking for. If I can determine the correct/expected method name (and parameters), I'm good to go.

Comment: I haven't done overloading using PowerShell till now, so it would be very interesting not only for me, to see how this is made. Thanks.

Comment: There's a good discussion of Powershell class concepts [here](https://xainey.github.io/2016/powershell-classes-and-concepts/), and good info on overloading in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4h19p8/overloaded_operators_with_powershell_v5_classes/), plus some semi-random information about it here on SO when you search on the Powershell tags and the keyword "overload".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The static method you should be able to define/overload on a Powershell class is [`op_Modulus`](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-powershell-pocket/9781449363369/ch01.html#windows_powershell_arithmetic_operators).

Answer (score 10):

To complement [Bender the Greatest's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59291513/45375):

Here's the complete **mapping of C# / PowerShell operator symbols / names to their `op_*` metadata method names** that must be used in implementing operator overloads in custom PowerShell classes (v5+); excerpted from the [Operator Overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/operator-overloads) chapter of the Framework Design Guidelines:

Note:

- The list is limited to those operators that you *can* overload in PowerShell, and even among these, only a subset may make sense in practice.
- Operators `-eq` and `-ne`, as well as `-lt` / `-le` and `-gt` / `-ge` must be overloaded using *different* methods - see below.

```
+   op_Addition 
-   op_Subtraction
*   op_Multiply
/   op_Division
%   op_Modulus
-bxor   op_ExclusiveOr
-band   op_BitwiseAnd
-bor    op_BitwiseOr
-shl    op_LeftShift
-shr    op_RightShift
-bnot   op_OnesComplement
```

**Important:**

- In general, operator overloading should be used judiciously (quoted from the linked page):

> **X AVOID** defining operator overloads, except in types that should feel like primitive (built-in) types.
> **✓ CONSIDER** defining operator overloads in a type that should feel like a primitive type.

- In PowerShell:

  - `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt` `-ge` must be overloaded indirectly, by implementing the `System.IComparable` interface.
  - Similarly, `-eq` and `-ne` must be overloaded by overriding the inherited `Object.Equals()` and `Object.GetHashCode()` methods.
  - The *binary* `+` and `-` operators are also applied to *unary* invocations; e.g., `+$var` is implicitly treated as `0 + $var`.
  - Compound assignments such as `+=` implicitly use overloaded operators.
  - `++` and `--` cannot be overloaded - they are hard-coded to operate on numeric types only.

---

#### Operator overloading example in PowerShell v5+:

This example defines a custom `[Fruit]` class that:

- overloads `+` via a static `op_Addition()` method, so you can "add" two instances.
- overloads `-eq` / `-ne` by overriding the `Object.Equals()` instance method and the associated `Object.GetHashCode()` method.
- overloads `-lt` / `-le` and `-gt` / `-ge` by implementing the `System.IComparable` interface via its `CompareTo()` instance method.

```
class Fruit : System.IComparable
{
    [string] $Kind
    Fruit([string] $Kind) { $this.Kind = $kind }

    # Operator overloading: Custom-define +
    # Note: must be static, return type must be the type at hand, 
    #       and the operands must both be of the type at hand.
    static [Fruit] op_Addition([Fruit] $a, [Fruit] $b) { return [Fruit]::new(('Cross-breed of {0} and {1}' -f $a.Kind, $b.Kind)) }
    
    # Custom-define -lt / -le and -gt / -ge, via the System.IComparable interface.
    [int] CompareTo([object] $other) {
      # Simply perform (case-insensitive) lexical comparison on the .Kind
      # property values.
      if ($this.Kind -eq $other.Kind) {return 0 }
      if ($this.Kind -lt $other.Kind) {return -1 }
      return 1 # -gt
    }

    # Custom-define -eq / -ne, by overriding Object.Equals()
    # Note that this also requires overriding Object.GetHashCode(),
    # because any two instances that compare the same must report the same
    # hash code.
    [bool] Equals([object] $other) {
      # Two [Fruit] instance, though distinct reference-type instances,
      # should be considered equal if their .Kind property is equal, case-insensitively.
      return $this.Kind -eq $other.Kind
    }
    # Since [Fruit] instances are compared by their .Kind property value (a [string]),
    # we defer to the latter's .GetHashCode() value, which seemingly is invariant 
    # for a given string. However, we normalize to *lowercase* first, given that 
    # PowerShell's string comparisons are case-insensitive by default.
    [int] GetHashCode() {
      return $this.Kind.ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode()
    }

}
```

You can now "add" to `[Fruit]` instances as follows:

```
PS> [Fruit]::new('orange') + [Fruit]::new('kiwi')

Kind
----
Cross-breed of orange and kiwi
```

That is, a new `[Fruit]` instance was returned whose `.Kind` property reflects the fruit that were "added" together.

```
# Two [Fruit] instances are considered equal if their .Kind property values
# are case-sensitively equal.
PS> [Fruit]::new('orange') -eq [Fruit]::new('Orange')
True
```

```
# Two [Fruit] instances are considered less / greater than based on 
# lexical comparison ('a' before 'b', ...), case-insensitively.
PS> [Fruit]::new('apple') -lt [Fruit]::new('orange')
True
```

---

#### Inspecting a given type for operator overloads:

- To test for comparison overloads (`-lt` / `-le` and `-gt` / `-ge`), see if an instance of the type implements `System.IComparable`:

  - `[Fruit]::new('apple') -is [IComparable]`
- There is *no* simple test for overloaded `-eq` / `-ne`, because the implementing `Equals()` and `Get-HashCode()` methods are by definition present on *all* objects. However, if the type at hand is a *reference type* (which all PowerShell custom classes are), you can *infer* from two distinct instances comparing as equal that `-eq` and `-ne` are overloaded; e.g., `[Fruit]::new('orange') -eq [Fruit]::new('orange')` yielding `$true` implies that `-eq` is overloaded.
- To test for an operator overload based on a static `op_*` method:

  - Either: Use an *instance* of the type and pipe to `Get-Member -Static`:

```
PS> [Fruit]::new('orange') | Get-Member -Static -Name op_*

   TypeName: Fruit

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
op_Addition Method     static Fruit op_Addition(Fruit a, Fruit b)
```

- Or: Use the *type itself* and pipe to `Get-Member -Static -Force` (the `-Force` is required in this case):

```
# Same output as above.
[Fruit] | Get-Member -Static -Force -Name op_*
```

Note that only truly *overloaded* operators surface this way.
Primitive .NET types such as `[int]` do *not* have such methods.

Comment: This answer shows up one of the deficiencies of the StackExchange model - I can only upvote this once; it's worth more than a mere 10 rep.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, @JeffZeitlin, and thank you for the nice feedback. Has there been discussion around this?

Comment: I don't believe so; I also suspect that if I were to broach the subject in network-Meta, I'd be told that that's what Bounties are for.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Yeah, I suppose a bounty clearly signals that the answer was worth something to you personally (like accepting, the originator is implied), but obviously comes at a cost. (To be clear: I'm not suggesting you do that here.)